# Regex inconsistency with VB6

Tags: regex, vb6

The question comes from an update to a quite old program in VB6 (I know what you thing about it, but please forgive me).

I had the old program to look for sentences in a text file beginning with a narrator identifier in the form: `L: "`, using the Regex pattern `[A-Z]: *`.
Everything was fine for years.

Now I need to add another match for any sentence **NOT** having a narrator; assuming `regX` is the Regex object and `myMatches` the matches collection, I simply test the `myMatches.count` to see if it `>0` and select the alternate path accordingly. The problem is that the next check (without a narrator) after a positive one (where narrator is present) anyway returns a `myMatches.count=1` even if this is not true, and the `myMatches.value` still shows the previous matching.

This even happens when I `set regX = nothing` and `set myMatches=nothing` at the end of the test too.

As a side problem, with `Set mM As Match` the statement: `mM = myMatches(1)` or `mM = myMatches.Item(1)` raises an error 'invalid call or wrong argument'.

**EDIT**
I try to include an example (I replaced the quotes in pattern and txt with a `!` to simplify the example):

```vb
Dim regX As RegExp
Dim myMatches As MatchCollection
Dim myMatch As Match
Dim patt as string
Dim txt as string

...  

Set regX = New RegExp
regX.IgnoreCase = False
regX.Global = True
patt ="[A-Z]: *!"
txt ="N: !This is a narrator phrase"

regX.Pattern = patt
Set myMatches = regX.Execute(txt)
If myMatches.Count > 0 Then   'narrator
    'I would use: Set myMatch=myMatches(1), but I get an error !, so I must use:'
    For Each myMatch In myMatches 
        ...do something...
    next
end if

patt = "\(.*\)"
txt="Another string, no narrator, no parenthesis)"
regX.Pattern = patt
Set myMatches = regX.Execute(txt)
If myMatches.Count > 0 Then   'this should be false
    'instead the flow comes here since myMatches.Count=1
end if
```

Hope this is clear enough

Comment: What is the code you're using to execute? What are some examples of strings you're testing? I'm not able to reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: `I would use: Set myMatch=myMatches(1), but I get an error` - that would be because the `Matches` collection is enumerated from zero, so you would need `Set myMatch=myMatches(0)`. I also cannot reproduce the problem with the code given. You probably should have not "simplified the example".

Comment: Thanks for the enumeration...it is a very dumb error myside. As far as the simplified code, I just replaced the quotes with a '!' to avoid this: patt="[A-Z]: *"+chr(34), and the txt="N: "+chr(34)+"This is a narrator phrase". The chr(34) seems confusing. Actually, the sentences are red from a text file and they already include the quotes. You mean that the second test with the parenthesis pattern does not return a positive match for you?

Comment: Btw, `myMatches.Count` is zero after second `Execute` here. I'm using a reference to `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression 5.5` (not `1.0`)

Comment: Well, I changed  to 'Set myMatch=myMatches(0)' (thanks again) and deleted the' For Each myMatch in myMatches' now unuseful...as in the tales then problem magically disappeared! I do not know why, but the important fact is that  now I can complete the update and forget the issue; as I said, this was something due from an old job.